# Prove $ \frac{1}{x-1} \approx \frac{1}{x}, x \gg 1 $

Tags: calculus, limits, approximation

I often found this form (and another similar type).
I can understand it intuitively, but I don't know how to prove it analytically

Comment: How do you define $\approx$?

Comment: Hint : Calculate the difference and show that it quickly converges to $0$ , if $x$ tends to $\infty$.

Comment: Take the limit $x\to\infty$ difference and ratio. Difference must be $0$. Ratio must be $1$.

Comment: For large $x$ we have $\frac{1}{2} x < x - 1 < x$ and thus $$\frac{1}{x} < \frac{1}{x-1} < 2 \frac{1}{x}.$$

Comment: @Ramanujan I found this equation as Wien approximation on Planck's radiation law, with x = hf/kT. The book didn't specify much about the limit for the frequency (f) or temperature (T). It just write that on high frequency, where hf/kT >> 1, the following approximation can be used

Comment: @lone student I understand the limit for difference ($ \lim _{x\to \infty }\left(1/x-1\right) = 0 $), but what does limit $ x \rightarrow \infty $ for ratio mean?

Comment: I mean, these are asymptotically equal.

Comment: The symbol $\approx$ doesn't have a fixed meaning but instead depends on exactly how good you want your approximations to be.  For example, the error of approximating $\frac1{x-1}$ by $\frac1x$ is $\frac1x-\frac1{x-1}=\frac{-1}{x(x-1)}\to 0$, and the relative error $\frac{\frac1x-\frac1{x-1}}{1/(x-1)}=\frac{-1}{x}\to 0$.

Comment: For $|x|>1$ we have $\frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{x^k}$ (geometric series). In particular, $\frac 1{x-1} = \frac 1x + O(\frac{1}{x^2})$, meaning the difference is bounded by a constant times $1/x^2$.

Answer (score 1):

What was probably intended is a Taylor expansion using the geometric series, assuming $|x|>1$, as follows. We have
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{x-1}&=\frac{1}{x}\cdot\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{x}}\\
&=\frac{1}{x}\cdot\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^n
\end{align}
The last equal sign is justified since our hypothesis $|x|>1$ implies $\left|\frac{1}{x}\right|<1$, and thus the geometric series can be used. So, one has
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{x-1}&=\frac{1}{x}+\mathcal{O}\left(\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^2\right)
\end{align}
i.e to first order in the quantity $1/x$, we have $\frac{1}{x-1}\approx \frac{1}{x}$. I should emphasize that there are several ways to interpret the vague (since we have no context) symbol $\approx$. In this answer, I have given you one possible way to interpret the approximation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $\dfrac {\frac1x}{\frac1{x-1}}=1-\frac1x \to 1$ as $x$ increases

Comment: But, this is not enough :-) For example, $$\frac{10^n+9^n}{10^n}\to 1$$ as $n\to\infty$. But $10^n+9^n-10^n =9^n\to \infty$ as $n\to\infty$. This diverge is too fast! So, we can not say that $$10^n≈10^n+9^n.$$ They are asymptotically equal. But, this is not helpful, I think.

Comment: @lonestudent That depends on you definition of $\approx$.  In your example with $n=100$ you would have $10^{100}+9^{100}$ being about $1.000027\times 10^{100}$ which many people might say is close (at least in relative terms) to $10^{100}$.  In the $\frac1x,\frac1{x-1}$ case, if you are worried about the absolute difference, then you can als0 say both have a limit of $0$ so their absolute difference also tends towards $0$ as $x$ increases

Comment: Yes, I agree this depends on definition . E.g my definition works for only $$\frac{n+100/n}{n+1/n}\to 1$$  as $n\to\infty$ and $$n+100/n-n-1/n\to 0$$ Then, $$n+1/n≈n+100/n$$.